# Drawing an isosceles triangle with Cevians from the base

Tags: euclidean-geometry

I would like to draw an isosceles triangle with certain conditions. $\triangle{ABC}$ is an isosceles triangle, and $AB$ is its base. From the endpoints of the base, cevians $AD$ and $BE$ are drawn. They partition the region bound by $\triangle{ABC}$ into four regions. The area of $\triangle{ABD}$ is 10, the area $\triangle{ABE}$ is 9, the area of the region under both cevians is 6, and the area of the remaining region is $(10+9)/2 = 9.5$. $AE : CE$ is $2:3$, and $BD : CD$ is $4:5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

\begin{align} 
S_{ABD}&=10
,\quad
S_{ABE}=9
,\quad
S_{ABP}=6
,\quad
S_{CEPD}=9.5
,\\
S_{ABC}&=S_{ABD}+S_{ABE}-S_{ABP}+S_{CEPD}
=\frac {45}2
,\\
|AC|=|BC|&=a
,\\
|BD|&=\tfrac49a
,\\
|CD|&=\tfrac59a
,\\
|AE|&=\tfrac25a
,\\
|CE|&=\tfrac35a
.
\end{align}

Let $|CH|=h_c$. Then
\begin{align} 
|AB|&=c=\frac{2S_{ABC}}{h_c}=\frac{45}{h_c}
,\\
|AC|=|BC|&=a=\sqrt{\frac{c^2}4+h_c^2}
=
\tfrac12\sqrt{\frac{2025}{h_c^2}+4h_c^2}
.
\end{align}

Using Stewart’s theorem,
we can express $|AD|^2$ and $|BE|^2$
in terms of $h_c$:

\begin{align} 
c^2\cdot \tfrac59a+
a^2\cdot \tfrac49a&=a(|AD|^2+\tfrac59\cdot\tfrac49 a^2)
,\\
c^2\cdot \tfrac35a+
a^2\cdot \tfrac25a&=a(|BE|^2+\tfrac35\cdot\tfrac25 a^2)
,\\
|AD|^2&=\frac{99225+16h_c^4}{81h_c^2}
.\\
|BE|^2&=
\tfrac4{25}\cdot\frac{8100+h_c^4}{h_c^2}
.
\end{align}

Using a Heron’s formula for the area
in terms of the squares of the sides,

\begin{align}
S&=\tfrac14\sqrt{4a^2b^2-(a^2+b^2-c^2)^2}
\end{align}
for 
$\triangle ABD$,
$\triangle ABE$
we can conclude that
these areas does not depend on $h_c$,
so the stated set of constraints is not enough
for unique solution:

choose any $h_c$, set $c=\frac{45}{h_c}$
and the points $A,B,C$ would be defined. Then split 
$AC,BC$ as stated to get $D$ and $E$.

For example, in the picture one more constraint was used:
$a=c$, to get equilateral triangle.
In this case we get

\begin{align}
h_c&=\sqrt{\frac{45\sqrt3}2}\approx 6.242687
,\\
a=b=c&=3^{3/4}\sqrt{10}
.
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
S_{ABD}&=
\tfrac14\cdot
\sqrt{4\cdot c^2\cdot|AD|^2-(c^2+|AD|^2-(\tfrac 49 a)^2)^2}
\\
&=
\tfrac14\cdot
\sqrt{4\cdot \left(\frac {45}{h_c}\right)^2
\cdot
\frac{99225+16h_c^4}{81h_c^2}
-
\left(\left(\frac {45}{h_c}\right)^2+
\frac{99225+16h_c^4}{81h_c^2}
-\frac{16}{81} 
\left( \frac{2025}{4h_c^2}+h_c^2 \right) 
\right)^2}
\\
&=
\tfrac14\,\sqrt{\frac{9922500+1600h_c^4}{hc^4}-\frac{9922500}{h_c^4}}
\equiv 10
.
\end{align}

---

Ups, in fact, it's much simpler:

\begin{align}
S_{ABD}&=
\frac{S_{ABD}}{S_{ABC}}\cdot S_{ABC}
\\
&=
\frac{\tfrac12\cdot \tfrac49 a\cdot h_a}{\tfrac12\cdot a\cdot h_a}
\cdot S_{ABC}
\\
&=\frac49\cdot S_{ABC}=\frac49\cdot \frac{45}2
\equiv 10
.
\end{align}

Comment: I appreciate your careful explanation.

Comment: The expressions that you have for the base and the legs of the isosceles triangle in terms of its height $h_{c}$ seem correct.

Comment: I wanted to verify them by showing that the area of $\triangle{ABD}$ is $10$.

Comment: If the length of $AD$ is denoted by $a$, the length of $BD$ is denoted by $b$, and the length of $AB$ is denoted by $c$, $4a^{2}b^{2} - (a^{2} + b^{2} - c^{2})^{2}$ should be equal to $1600$.

Comment: $a^{2} = (99225 + 16h^{4})/h^{2}$.

Comment: $b^{2} = 16/81 \cdot (2025 + 4h^{4})/(4h^{2})$.

Comment: $c^{2} = (45/h)^{2}$.

Comment: I did not get a constant.

Comment: A constant $81$ is missing in  $|AD|^2=\frac{99225+16h_c^4}{81h_c^2}$.

Comment: Excuse my carelessness. Thanks!

Comment: See mode details on the calculation of $S_{ABD}$.
Also, to convince yourself, try to set 
$h_c$ to some convenient number, say $5$ or $9$
and check numerically.

Comment: Your demonstration is lucid. I know the lengths of the legs and base of all the isosceles that give the requisite areas!

Comment: The bounty is for you; I have to wait to award it.